# Restore Docker MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm new to Docker and learning about it. I'm using a Docker container of MySQL and I have created two databases with populated tables.

I've pushed the image to Docker Hub so I can use it on another device but I've tried several times whenever I pull my MySQL repository and run it I don't see any of my databases. I think I'm doing it the wrong way.

[Mysql Databases from the pulled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaICm.png)

How can I push the MySQL image with its two databases to Docker Hub the right way?

Comment: Is your DB stored in your container? If so, it won't exist in your image. Please share your `docker-compose.yml` and/or `Dockerfile` files so we can see how you have configured your environment. Also, how are you creating your image?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, I copied this command to create the image "docker container run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123 -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql" 
I think the "mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql" part means that the DB will be stored in the container, if that's what it means how can I solve this?

Comment: If you want the data to be in the image, you need to create the database and populate it during the building of the image (with RUN statements)..

Comment: @HansKilian how can i do that, can you give me an example or a tutorial link, thank you.

Comment: @NadaAlbargawi Tbh., I don't think that's a good solution. If you embed the database in the image, you can't update it. Every time you bring the container down and start a new one, the database will be back to the initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have the database included in your image, you can have SQL scripts in your image that creates the database and populates it with initial data.

If you put files ending in .sh, .sql or .sql.gz in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory in the image, they will be run the first time the container is run.

If you have an SQL script to initialize your database, you can include it in the image by having a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM mysql:latest
COPY initialize-database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Then you can run the container and map /var/lib/mysql to a docker volume that will store the database like this

```
docker run --rm -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql <my-image-name>
```